# How to do silent update in android App

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

How to do silent update in Android App

it's possible to update the app in silently. i.e (no user interaction)

what is the best way to achieve that? thank you in advance

Comment: This is a bad idea in regions where mobile plans have quotas...

Comment: only system apps can in theory do it. You can't do it in a regular app in common way. But there still is a way, but it is hard. You can use dynamic class loading to do that. You can dynamically load the compiled DEX file, which you can download whenever you want, and run the code from it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko thank you I'll try my best i'm come back with my experience

Comment: The best way to do is build a web view/native app which changes it's functionality depending upon a pre-built API server instructions. Quora is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have published your app in playstore and you want to update your app , then there is no way except the user has turned on AutoUpdate and update will run in background.

But if you have not published your android app in playstore and you want to update your app , then you should run [Service in background](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) and should link some flags from your database to notify the app about update.
and after that your app should have background Service for updating the app but that will also need permission for update. So practically I think it is Impossible without permission.

Comment: but this doesn't answer the question. The question ishow to update app without user interaction. Not how to notify user about an update.

Comment: yes @NIKUNJ KHOKHAR I'm not going published app in Playstore. my updated version also in my local memory. how to update that APK